# Can anyone suggest more technical resources for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-community, resources

I was able to find few articles on Magento 2  from

1. http://magenticians.com/
2. http://www.thienphucvx.com/

If anybody know some other resources can you please share it here? (links, Ebooks, blogs etc)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about magento 2's official documentation ?

- http://devdocs.magento.com/

AFAIK, Alan Kents Blog is the best resource for magento 2 so far

- https://alankent.wordpress.com/page/2/

Alan's blog is not tutorial oriented but his own perspective view on different subjects. But it is very helpful to know about advancement in magento 2 project.

Magentician is also a good reference.

I don't think ebooks are available for magento 2 right now, since it is in its very early stage.

The best resource to study about Magento 2 so far : **[AlanStorm's Article](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/)**

### EDIT

This answer is quite old. For more Magento2 resources, please refer **[@FireBear's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79973/3535)**.

Answer (score 16):

- You can track all updates and Magento Community news at Twitter with [#magento2](https://twitter.com/hashtag/magento2) and [#realmagento](https://twitter.com/hashtag/realmagento) tags.
- [Official Magento 2 Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/)
- [Gitller chat for Magento 2 developers](https://gitter.im/magento/magento2)
- Official tutorial training from Magento - [Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development](http://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development#.Ve4RqJ2eDRY)
- Alan Storm [Magento 2](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2) tutorials, must read!
- Magento2 tutorials, screencasts and up to date news from [MageClass](http://mageclass.com/)
- [Magento 2 Developer’s Cookbook](http://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-developers-cookbook-useful-code-snippets-tips-notes.html): Useful Code Snippets, Tips, and Notes
- [Magento 2 Articles Collection](http://www.coolryan.com/magento-2/) by Cool Ryan
- [The Ultimate Magento 2 Tutorial](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-ultimate-magento-2-tutorial.html) - collection of tutorials
- [Create Magento 2 Blog Extension from scratch](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/) (Setup,Models, Migrations, Database Schema, Controllers, Blocks, Layouts & views, Unit testing) by Ash Smith
- [Learning Magento 2](https://github.com/creatuity/LearningMagento2) & The Magento 2 Learning Curve - community driven resource list by Joshua Warren

We trying to collect best Magento 2 Community resources and keep them updated in our [Magento 2 Developer Resource List](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-ultimate-magento-2-developer-resource-list-docs-tools-books-courses.html)

Answer (score 7):

Magento 2 official documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/

Answer (score 4):

There is also the Magento 2 developer hub at http://magento.com/developers/magento2 which contains links to a number of resources. It is the official home page for Magento 2 developers - that is, we are trying to link various good (more official) sources of information from this single page.

For example, there are a few videos linked from the page as well as Ben Marks' blog.

Answer (score 2):

you can also find the technical blogs. please follow the below links.

1. http://blog.magestore.com/magento-2/
2. http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/

If I am got more links I will share with you guys.

But I suggest that first we need to read the Default Magento2 official site documentation. Because they have change so many thing like Folder structure, Module Structure, Configuration files, Added Composer etc.That is very good for Developers.

Comment: Shameless, there are few but important resource on Magento 2 - http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/category/magento2/

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful technical resources that I usually follow to improve Magento 2 knowledge that are:

1. Magento explorer - tutorial from beginner to advanced level:
   http://magentoexplorer.com/
2. Alanstorm blog - only advanced tutorials, recommended for developers only: http://alanstorm.com/
3. Inchoo - http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/
4. Mage plaza - https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend this 12 hours course on Udemy. It teaches the core concept with real live project. https://www.udemy.com/simplified-magento-2-video-course-from-beginner-to-expert/ Disclaimer: I was part of the creator of the course.

After that, you can go for Magento study group. I found it quite useful https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer