# how do get custom block in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I magento 1 i can call `{{block type="Xanka\Slider\Block\Slideshow" template="slideshow.phtml"}}`. how do it in magento2?

Answer (score 1):

First you should take a look at some of the magento 2 resources available ([Can anyone suggest more technical resources for Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52753/can-anyone-suggest-more-technical-resources-for-magento-2/52754)) or http://devdocs.magento.com/

In terms of adding a block, I'm assuming through the CMS you can use the following:

```
{{block class="Xanka\\Slider\\Block\\Slideshow" block_id="block_identifier" template="slideshow.phtml"}}
```