# How to modify magento programatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-community

I have no clue how to modify files in magento. I found some php files to create order in magento programatically but i have no clue where to place these files to make them run.
I am pitty confuse by the architecture of magento. Please help me with that?

Comment: I recommend you purchase Magento's new training course (Fundamentals of Magento 2). It's fairly in-depth, and should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Take a look around: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52753/can-anyone-suggest-more-technical-resources-for-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

You can start understanding magento from official doc @ http://devdocs.magento.com/

Also there are certain blogs and tutorial on google which will help you through.