# Magento2 how can i study fully magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, link, download-link

Any one tell me how can i study magento2 fully any free material or tutorial is there

Need Help

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the best site where you can lean Magento 2 step by step very easily.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html

From FireBear

- You can track all updates and Magento Community news at Twitter with [#magento2](https://twitter.com/hashtag/magento2) and [#realmagento](https://twitter.com/hashtag/realmagento) tags.
- [Official Magento 2 Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/)
- [Gitller chat for Magento 2 developers](https://gitter.im/magento/magento2)
- Official tutorial training from Magento - [Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development](http://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development#.Ve4RqJ2eDRY)
- Alan Storm [Magento 2](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2) tutorials, must read!
- Magento2 tutorials, screencasts and up to date news from [MageClass](http://mageclass.com/)
- [Magento 2 Developer’s Cookbook](http://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-developers-cookbook-useful-code-snippets-tips-notes.html): Useful Code Snippets, Tips, and Notes
- [Magento 2 Articles Collection](http://www.coolryan.com/magento-2/) by Cool Ryan
- [The Ultimate Magento 2 Tutorial](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-ultimate-magento-2-tutorial.html) - collection of tutorials
- [Create Magento 2 Blog Extension from scratch](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/) (Setup,Models, Migrations, Database Schema, Controllers, Blocks, Layouts & views, Unit testing) by Ash Smith
- [Learning Magento 2](https://github.com/creatuity/LearningMagento2) & The Magento 2 Learning Curve - community driven resource list by Joshua Warren

We trying to collect best Magento 2 Community resources and keep them updated in our [Magento 2 Developer Resource List](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-ultimate-magento-2-developer-resource-list-docs-tools-books-courses.html)

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79973/35758

Comment: I found that Magento learning curve is a nightmare, extremely hard to learn..